# Ruby on Rails 3: AJAX call not refreshing div with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, link-to

I am new to Ruby on Rails and i am working through a few example applications in the O'Reilly Head First Rails book.  In one of the examples there is a page made up of three partials.  The middle partial is a list of items.  There is a link right below this section that, when clicked, should refresh the div containing that partial.  The book is running examples based off of Rails 2.3 i believe and i am using Rails 3.1.  This is the example that the book is giving me:

routes.rb:

```
map.connect '/flights/:flight_id/seats', :action=>'flight_seats', :controller=>'seats'
```

seats_controller.rb:

```
def flight_seats
    @flight = Flight.find(params[:flight_id])
    render :partial => "flights/seat_list", :locals => {:seats => @flight.seats}
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<div id="seats">
    <%= render :partial=>"seat_list". :locals=>{:seats=>@flight.seats} %>
</div>

<$= link_to_remote("Refresh Seats", :url=>"/flights/#{@flight.id}/seats", method=>"get", :update=>"seats") %>
```

This example is also using prototype.js since that's what Rails 2.3 came with built in.  Rails 3 has jQuery as the default JavaScript library. (not sure if that makes a big difference)

Here is what i have so far.  This is getting the contents of the partial correctly, it's just not updating the "seats" div after the AJAX call gets the partial.  My code:

routes.rb:

```
match 'flights/:flight_id/seats' => 'seats#flights_seats'
```

seats_controller.rb:

```
def flights_seats
    @flight = Flight.find(params[:flight_id])

    render :partial => "flights/seat_list", :locals => { :seats => @flight.seats }
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<div id="seats">
    <%= render :partial => 'seat_list', :locals => { :seats => @flight.seats } %>
</div>

<%= link_to "Refresh Seats", "/flights/#{@flight.id}/seats", :remote => true %>
```

Any idea why my `<div id="seats">` won't refresh with the updated partial?  I'm betting there is but i'll ask anyway, is something wrong with my code?

Comment: `:update => "seats"` won't work with jQuery.  You'll need to write some javascript to handle the AJAX response. There are many examples of Rails3/jQuery/AJAX out there

Comment: Ok, so instead of using `:update` i now have to write my own custom JavaScript to handle the response?  Any idea why `:update` was deprecated in Rails 3?  I'm assuming there was a reason.

Comment: Yes, you need to write your own javascript now, but it's easy to do.  This was done to avoid inline javascript, and brittle code in views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The :remote => true option is a bit weird if you aren't returning JSON data.  You can wrap your HTML in a JSON object, though, which is what I typically do.  Or if you want something closer to your existing code something like this should work for you:

`<%= link_to "Refresh Seats", "/flights/#{@flight.id}/seats", :class => "refresh-seats" %>`

In your javascript somewhere:

```
$(document).delegate(".refresh-seats", "click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#seats").load(this.href);
});
```

Comment: That works great! Thanks for the example code.  There was one minor flaw though. ;)  You forgot the `#` before `seats` in your selector.  Thanks for the help....i've been learning that there is a lot that has changed with Rails 3+.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it worked, and I updated my answer to fix the syntax error.